# How to vertically align this two columns in a Joomla 2.5 template?

Tags: html, css, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-template

I have some problem with the following Joomla 2.5 template (or maybe with the CSS style of a module).

If you go here you can understand what I mean: http://onofri.org/scorejava/

As you can see in the main content area I have two columns (created by two differnts instances of a module named "Featured Categories", this one: http://www.joomlacsszengarden.com/joomla16/index.php/featured-categories )

The two columns have titles "Articoli più letti" and "Ultimi articoli".

You can see that the title of the first column is not vertically aligned with the title of the second column.

I have try to understand why using Firebug but for the moment I have not find a solution...

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rt-block` class has 15px padding by default. The right block (with 'ultimi') has padding 0 because it's wrapped by a different block.

See the code below:

```
<div id="rt-content-bottom">
    <div class="rt-grid-5 rt-alpha">
        <div class="rt-block">
...
    <div class="rt-grid-4 rt-omega">
       <div class="rt-block">
```

and css:

```
rt-main .rt-container .rt-grid-6 .rt-block, #rt-main .rt-container .rt-grid-4 .rt-block {
padding: 0;
} 

.rt-block { margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 15px; position: relative; }
```

Just set the same padding value to both .rt-grid-5 .rt-block and rt-grid-4 .rt-block

Comment: So, I have only to add a: padding:15px; to the following elements: .rt-grid-5 .rt-block and rt-grid-4 .rt-block ???

Comment: template.css (line 77): change `-main .rt-container .rt-grid-6 .rt-block, #rt-main .rt-container .rt-grid-4 .rt-block` to `-main .rt-container .rt-grid-6 .rt-block, .rt-grid-5 .rt-block, #rt-main .rt-container .rt-grid-4 .rt-block` (add .rt-grid-5 .rt-block) to the list

Comment: oh yeah !!! This seems to work well !!! Thank you so much...I hate to work with CSS...I am very bad in this thing